# What's the purpose of Create GUID tool in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, guid, create-guid

Visual Studio has a Create GUID tool (Tools > Create GUID).

What is it for? Can you remember what was the last time you used it?

I just can't imagine why i should copy into the clipboard a new GUID with that tool.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Could the purpose of the 'Create GUID tool' be to... create GUIDs?  Maybe the question you should be asking is why you would need a GUID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a very useful tool for those who develop and maintain COM components. Need to introduce a new registry-exposed class or interface? You need a new GUID. With this tool you click "New GUID", select "Registry format", copy it to the clipborad and then paste into a IDL file.

Answer (score 4):

[WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (installer toolkit) projects require a lot of GUIDs. I use it often and often.

Answer (score 3):

I've used it many times to get a GUID without having to write and run some code or open SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Absolutely, I have gone into my database SOOO Many times to copy a stinking Guid out of the database... I wish I had a feature like this!

Comment: osql -E -Q "select newid()"
:)

Comment: DOH! Its that familiar feeling of stupidity creeping up again!

Comment: Haha. Yeah I'm always using linqpad for that mess.

Answer (score 1):

GUIDs are very useful when you wish to create a unique identifier to a resource.

In C# you can use :

```
System.Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Guid("8B92766B-825F-409d-BC32-B3723D617A93"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ProgId("Apollo.WS"), ComVisible(true)]
public sealed class WS : ServicedComponent, IWSFSAPLProxy {}
```

Here you have. That GUID came from the Create GUID tool